# class appearing in my code I didnt write

Tags: html, css

Ive been working on an assignment for college and ive run into a problem where a class is appearing in two of my images that I did not write

The code works fine when I preview it locally but when I upload it on the server this code appears within my img tag.

This class is preventing the images from appearing altogether. I have 2 other images using identical code just different images and they work perfectly.

HTML:

```
<img src="Images/twitter.png"
onmouseover="this.src='Images/twitterHover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/twitter.png'" 
style="width:51px; height:51px; margin-bottom:-14px; margin-left:-22px;" alt="twitter">

<img src="Images/google+.png"
onmouseover="this.src='Images/google+Hover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/google+.png'" 
style="width:51px; height:51px; margin-bottom:-14px; margin-left:-22px;" alt="google+">
```

The HTML on the server:

```
<img class="ddhedzvztqbrlruhkpci" src="Images/twitter.png"
onmouseover="this.src='Images/twitterHover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/twitter.png'" 
style="width:51px; height:51px; margin-bottom:-14px; margin-left:-22px;" alt="twitter">

<img src="Images/google+.png"
onmouseover="this.src='Images/google+Hover.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='Images/google+.png'" 
style="width:51px; height:51px; margin-bottom:-14px; margin-left:-22px;" alt="google+">
```

Heres a link to the server

http://mlemon.imgd.ca/Proj2/

Comment: What server are you using? What process are you using to upload it?

Comment: Im using a cpanel server provided by my college. Im just simply uploading the html/css/image/font files into folders on the sever.

Comment: I can't find the class you provided in the DOM inspector? Are you sure it's in your live version? (i'm looking at the twitter icon inside the header)

Comment: This sounds like a question for your prof/TA for your course, as it is likely specific to the environment you are running in. I assume this isnt a problem when viewing your page from source (without uploading it)?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Umm ive been saving my current version of the index.html and uploading it to the server. When I view the index.html on my server the code class="ddhedzvztqbrlruhkpci" has randomly appeared in my img tags.

Comment: Yes Chris, it works perfectly fine when I view it from locally.

Comment: After messing around with my code a bit I believe the problem lies with the images themselves. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I had this exact problem with an image named 'dwit_ad1.jpeg'. Changed the name to 'dwit_ad.jpeg' and it began working without errors. Really strange issue, I'm interested if anyone knows what's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a class for each image and place the style codes inside style.css. It'll probably work.